# How to click mouse automatically without clicking mouse

Tags: java, swing, awtrobot

I'm making a project in java. In this i'm using **speech recognition**. Now i want to click button when i speak **click**. I want to know how to click mouse automatically?

Comment: `java.awt.Robot` can do that.

Comment: Why would you "fake" a mouse click? Just put the code you would execute when the mouse would have been clicked, in the event that is fired when you say **click**

Answer (score 0):

> Now i want to click button when i speak click.

You can use:

```
button.doClick(...);
```